# Encrypted String to byte[]

Tags: java, encryption, arrays, password-encryption, jce

I need to encrypt password i am using [this](http://www.mkyong.com/java/jce-encryption-data-encryption-standard-des-tutorial/) tutorial

i need to store the encrypted password in sql data base as a string, when i try to read and convert string to byte[] i have a problem , the byte[] is different from original encrypted byte[]

```
byte[] encrypted = encryper.encrypte("pavel");

            Log.i("info","encrypted : "+encrypted);

            String pass = String.valueOf(encrypted);

            byte[] passBytes = pass.getBytes();

            Log.i("info","passBytes : "+passBytes);

            Log.i("info","decrypted : "+encryper.decrypte(passBytes));
```

log

```
I/info: encrypted : [B@3832a394
I/info: passBytes : [B@33deee3d
I/info: decrypted :
```

decrypt method

```
public String decrypte(byte[] text)
{

    byte[] textDecrypted = new byte[0];

    try {

        cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, myDesKey);
        textDecrypted = cipher.doFinal(text);
        Log.i("info","do final : "+textDecrypted);

    }catch (InvalidKeyException e) {e.printStackTrace();
    }catch (IllegalBlockSizeException e){e.printStackTrace();}
    catch (BadPaddingException e){e.printStackTrace();}

    return new String(textDecrypted);
}
```

but if i write public String decrypte(byte[] text)
    {

```
    byte[] textDecrypted = new byte[0];

    try {

        cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, myDesKey);
        textDecrypted = cipher.doFinal(text);
        Log.i("info","do final : "+textDecrypted);

    }catch (InvalidKeyException e) {e.printStackTrace();
    }catch (IllegalBlockSizeException e){e.printStackTrace();}
    catch (BadPaddingException e){e.printStackTrace();}

    return new String(textDecrypted);
}
```

but if i put the original byte[] all work

```
encryper.decrypte(encrypted)
```

Comment: About your requirements: If you are doing that work to learn something/for fun: Great! If you are planning to acurally store passwords DES encrypted in a database: Don't do it. Attackers that have access to the database can retrieve the password. Instead, store a **salted** hash with a method that intentionally makes retrieval slow. For more information see https://nakedsecurity.sophos.com/2013/11/20/serious-security-how-to-store-your-users-passwords-safely/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would encode the byte array to String using Base64.Encoder (java.util, since Java 8), then save it to DB, then read it from DB to String and decode it to byte array using Base64.decoder

Answer (score 1):

What you are seeing on the console is the result of the `toString()` method of `byte[]`. It doesn't represent the actual contents. Instead it is an ID for the object. They are different because you have different objects.

Also if you use `String.valueOf(encrypted)` it will fall back to the [`valueOf(Object)` method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#valueOf(java.lang.Object)) because there is no `valueOf(byte[])`. This gives you not a string representation of the contents of your array, but the same object ID produced by `toString()`.

Use e.g. [`new String(encrypted)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#String(byte[])) to convert the contents of the byte array to a readable string.

Comment: when i use  new String(encrypted) i have �+��^�$ its normal? and i am not understand how i convert the string in data base to byte[]?

Comment: That seems like a problem with the encoding. There are also constructors where you can specify the encoding you are using.